# PC connection to iPhone hotspot disconnects even with high speed connection

Tags: tethering

I am connecting a Widows 10 PC laptop to an iPhone XS hotspot.  The connection periodically drops even though it is a high speed connection.  To reconnect I have to go back to the iPhone and open the Personal Hotspot screen; then the PC connects.  Why would this happen?

While the connection is high speed the location that the iPhone is in is very "particular" when it comes to cell coverage.  There are areas that are better than others and the iPhone can go down to one bar if not in the correct placement. Even though it can drop to one bar the iPhone still has Internet access; the phone doesn't completely lose Internet access so I'm not clear why the PC would lose the connection.

Comment: Which connection drops?  The connection to the phone or the phone’s connection to the Internet?

Comment: PC connection to the hotspot

Comment: Have you tried it using WiFi instead?  Your LTE signal has nothing to do with your USB connection they are completely separate. You may have van problem with either/both the USB ports on the Mac or phone, the cable may be bad or the phone of flaky.  Can you try it on a friends phone to test out?

Comment: I’m connecting to the iPhone hotspot from the PC using WIFI.  I haven’t tried USB..

Comment: You tagged "tethering" which is a USB connection.  Is your WiFi connection dropping or is your phone dropping the internet?  Which connection is dropping out and how are you determining it's dropping?  When it drops, what's the IP address of your Mac?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It’s the wifi connection dropping.  The phone internet seems ok.